# Trying to update record in mongodb using mongoose. My application is using Node.js and Express 4

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, pug

I am building web application to track baseball players.The only data attributes associated with the players currently is fName and lName. I am using Node.js Express 4, mongoose, and Jade. I have the get request functioning properly when you click on a player it will take you to localhost:3000/player/:id with the players information correctly loaded into the view.I am having issues with my post method and getting it to actually update the player information on submit. Instead of updating the player my post method is just adding a new player.

Here is the code for the get request that seems to be functioning properly:

```
    router.get('/:id', function(req,res){
       Player.find({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, player){
        if(err){
          res.redirect('/error');
        }else{
          res.render(
            'editPlayer',
            player[0]
          );
        }
      });
    });
```

Here is the code for the post that is creating a new player and not updating the current player:

```
    router.post('/:id', function(req,res){

       Player.where({ _id: req.params.id }).update({ fName: req.body.fName, lName: req.body.lName });

       res.redirect('player');
    });
```

Here is editPlayer.jade which contains the form I am using to update the player:

```
    extends layout

    block content

      block content
        h1 #{fName} #{lName}
        form(method="post" action="/#{_id}")
          input(type="hidden" value=_id name="id")
          label(for="fName") First Name:
          input(type="text", name="fName", value=fName)
          label(for="lName") Last Name:
          input(type="text", name="lName", value=lName)
          input(type="submit", value="Save")
```

If there is any more information that would be helpful please let me know. Thank you for your time in advance,
-fred k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see... don't you want a findOne() call instead of a find() in the router code?

It's probably just that you need to swap req.params.id with req.body.id, btw.

You might try this style in the POST... (noting the use of req.body.id here instead of req.param.id, for example)

```
router.post('/:id', function(req,res) {
  Player.findOne({})
    .where('_id').equals(req.body.id)
    .exec(function(err, playerRecord) {
    if (playerRecord) {
      playerRecord.fName = req.body.fName;
      playerRecord.lName = req.body.lName;
      playerRecord.save();
      console.log('player/:id replace successful with Player record');
    } else {
      console.log('POST player/:id err');
    } // End of if (playerRecord)
    res.redirect('player');
  }); // End of Player.findOne
}); // End of router.post
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much for the help. I hate to say but the code you provided runs with no errors but similarly to what I already have it is just adding a new player and not actually editing the one selected.

Comment: At this point I think I'd add a console.log() there just inside which will log what the incoming _id is.  It may surprise you.  Note that you have this code [input(type="hidden" value=_id name="id")] which I don't think I've done.  I usually do something like pass the variable into Jade [res.render('player', { playerId: _id });] and then [input(type="hidden" value="#{playerId}" name="id")]

Comment: Dude you awesome. I am working on solution now but the console logs have shown me that the application currently isn't using the right post method. It is instead hitting this post which is the one I am using to create new players.

`router.post('/', function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body.id);
  new Player({fName : req.body.fName,lName : req.body.lName})
  .save(function(err, player) {
    res.redirect('player');
  });
});`

Comment: Nice!  So that would explain why it's seemingly ignoring your attempts and doing its own thing.  Console-logging is the only real way to troubleshoot a number of things like asynchronous race conditions, for example.  Node's relatively new to me, too, and it often surprises me how different the underlying platform is to others I'm more familiar with.

Comment: Hey so after constant failed attempts and getting my routing to operate right I ended up just stealing some boilerplate code from https://www.airpair.com/javascript/complete-expressjs-nodejs-mongodb-crud-skeleton to use. Thank you for your help tho.